# Android Pre Dex PARSE ERROR on Scala

Tags: android, scala, akka, gluon

I am trying to build Gluon application with Akka. Building for API 22. Everytime I try to run it, I successfully compile other dependencies (I see them in bottom panel) but always get problem with Scala or Akka, however, everytime I run it, error is on other line/file.

[image]

Comment: You must build using sbt. And scala 2.12 will not work on android at all. Period.

Comment: What is newest Scala/Akka version, that will run? Please post everything as an answer, so I can accept it, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala 2.11.8 is the current and latest version that will run on android.

I don't know about akka as it is not a good fit on android.

Comment: Akka 2.3.x is the last version to support Java 6 and has been reported to run on Android.  See example using macroid [here](http://macroid.github.io/modules/Akka.html).